# Jquery validation remote not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

I am using violin to validate if the email or username is unique but the remote option is not working and i have no clue why.

here is my js code

```
$('.form').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: "../app/Codecourse/Validation/Validator.php/",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    email: function() { 
                        return $( "#email" ).val();
                    }                       
                }
            }
        },
        username: {
            required: true,
            rangelength: [6,16],
            alpha: true,
            remote: {
                url: "../app/Codecourse/Validation/Validator.php/",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    username: function() {
                        return $( "#username" ).val();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

and here is my php validation class that extends violin

```
class Validator extends Violin {

    protected $user;
    protected $hash;
    protected $auth;

    public function __construct(User $user, Hash $hash, $auth = null) {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->hash = $hash;
        $this->auth = $auth;

        $this->addFieldMessages([
            'email' => [
                'uniqueEmail' => 'That email is already in use.'
            ],
            'username' => [
                'uniqueUsername' => 'That username is already in use.'
            ]
        ]);

        $this->addRuleMessages([
            'matchesCurrentPassword' => 'That does not match your current password'
        ]);
    }

    public function validate_uniqueEmail($value, $input, $args) {
        $user = $this->user->where('email', $value);

        if ($this->auth && $this->auth->email === $value) {
            return true;
        }

        return ! (bool) $user->count();
    }

    public function validate_uniqueUsername($value, $input, $args) {
        return ! (bool) $this->user->where('username', $value)->count();
    }

    public function validate_matchesCurrentPassword($value, $input, $args) {
        if ($this->auth && $this->hash->passwordCheck($value, $this->auth->password)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

i said in the comments that i could submit but apparently i can't even submit the form even if it is not a unique email or username

does anyone have any suggestion that can help me solve my problem?

Comment: Is the request being send on submit? If so, what is the response, and what is the post data?

Comment: if i use a unique email and username i can submit but if its no longer unique i am unable to send it

Comment: Isn't that the idea of the validation?? Not able to send if it is not unique.

Comment: yes it is but its not showing the message error, thats where the problem lies

Comment: you should not return false then. You should return the error message

Comment: The response of the validation call should either be `true` for a valid form field, or the error message for invalid form fields. So the function `validate_uniqueEmail` for instance should return the error message and not `false`

Comment: I'll create an answer for 'rep-sake' ;)

Comment: apparently i was wrong and it wasnt even submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response of the validation call should either be `true` for a valid form field, or the error message for invalid form fields. So the function `validate_uniqueEmail` for instance should return the error message and not `false`